# Go batch insert Returning ID not working

Tags: postgresql, go

I want to batch insert some rows and get their ids with golang, this is my attempt in doing so

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/bmizerany/pq"
    "log"
)
func main() {
conn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require", host, user, password, dbname)
d, err := sql.Open("postgres", conn)
rows, err := d.Query("INSERT INTO MYTABLE(MYCOLUMN) VALUES(1),(2),(3) RETURNING ID")
defer rows.Close()
var ids []int
for rows.Next() {
    var id int
    scan_err := rows.Scan(&id)
    fmt.Println(scan_err)
    if scan_err != nil {
        log.Fatal(scan_err)
    }
    ids = append(ids, id)
    fmt.Printf("id %d\n", id)
}
}
```

my problem is `ids` is always empty even if the values are inserted correctly in the database.

what's interesting is that the following works

```
var id int
db.QueryRow("INSERT INTO MYTABLE(MYCOLUMN) VALUES(1) RETURNING ID").Scan(&id)
```

How do solve this?

Comment: The errors you're ignoring might produce some valuable info for troubleshooting.

Comment: The errors are nil i already checked and as i already mentioned the values were inserted successfully in the database @Adrian

Comment: Try Exec instead of Query, as it's insert of a single row. You can also try using LastInsertId() from it's result. Query is meant for SELECT. See http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html

Comment: This may be something related to the driver you're using. How many rows are you getting back? What happens if you try a QueryRow with the batch insert and Scan a single int?

Comment: @KrzysztofKowalczyk The OP's question is regarding getting the IDs from multiple inserted values. `VALUES(1),(2),(3)`

Comment: The minimum example in question works for me, i.e. I got 3 IDs. Are you sure there is no other code lines that may causing the error/unexpected result (empty ID) ?